# Can you call an asynchronous function/method directly with a .then?

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous, promise

I have some code here where I am logging a user into firebase using firebase auth. I instantiate a new user in my app.js file, call the signIn method on that object, then in my signIn method of the user class, i am console loggin the return credential from firebase auth.  I am also returning the credential to the object that called it and console logging the credential again.  When I use async / await, the code runs just as I expect: it logs the credential in the signIn method first, then again in the app.js right after I call signIn.

However, when I try to do it using the .then approach, the console.log in my app.js file shows undefined before the console log in the signIn method of the User class.  However, the console log in the signIn method of the User class returns the correct credential.

My question is: why isn't the console log in my app.js file waiting to get the credential before console logging?  Or at least console logging a promise?

```
   class User {
        constructor(email, password){
            this.email = email;
            this.password = password;
            this.cred;
        }

        async signUp(){
            const cred = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password);
            return cred;
        }

        async signIn() {

            auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email,this.password).then(cred=>{
                console.log(cred);
                return cred;
            });

            //this async/await code below works as expected 
            // const cred = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email,this.password);
            // console.log(cred);
            // return cred;
        }

        signOut(){

        }
    }

    export default User


   // beginning of my app.js file

   loginForm && loginForm.addEventListener('submit', async e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const user = new User(loginForm.email.value,loginForm.password.value);

        //const cred = await user.signIn(); // this async/await code works fine
        //console.log(cred); 

            user.signIn().then(cred => { 
              console.log(cred); // this console.log fires before the console.log in signIn() and returns undefined
              loginForm.reset();
            })
        });
```

Comment: Your `signIn()` needs to return the Promise inside. Currently it returns nothing, which is why `user.signIn().then()` shouldn't work at all.

Comment: Because signIn doesn't *return* the promise, so it's not part of the chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you should note that [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) functions essentially just another way to express Promise-based workflows. When you mark a function as async, you're basically saying that this function will return a Promise, and when you use await within an async function, you're basically saying the rest of this function will be part of the `.then` callback of that implicit Promise.

Getting to your question, `signIn()` is marked as async, meaning it returns a promise (which is why `signIn().then` doesn't throw a TypeError), and inside it you're creating a promise (`auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword`), but that promise is not tied to the implicit Promise of `signIn`, so the implicit promise resolves immediately. In other words, your original version of `signIn` is equivalent to:

```
signIn() {
  auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email,this.password).then((cred) => {
    console.log(cred);
    return cred;
  });
  return Promise.resolve(undefined);
}
```

To fix this behavior, you need to remove the `async` keyword from `signIn` and return the promise from `signIn` if you want to use `.then` outside of it. For example:

```
signIn() {
  return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email,this.password).then((cred) => {
    console.log(cred);
    return cred;
  });
}
```

The above code is, in fact, equivalent to this async/await version:

```
async signIn() {
  const cred = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email,this.password);
  console.log(cred);
  return cred;
}
```

Note though that in your event listener, you're not awaiting the promise, so it will resolve before the `signIn` promise is completed. That is to say, your original event handler is equivalent to:

```
e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const user = new User(loginForm.email.value,loginForm.password.value);
  user.signIn().then(cred => { 
    console.log(cred);
    loginForm.reset();
  });
  return Promise.resolve(undefined);
}
```

This is *probably* doesn't mean anything for you, since DOM events either don't care about the return value of the callback or respect promises. It's a distinction that could be important in some scenarios (e.g. `e.preventDefault()` won't work if you call it inside a `.then` / after an `async`)

Comment: Awesome.  It works now and this makes sense that I need to return the promise.  Just to make sure I fully understand though -  to your last point "Note though that in your event listener, you're not awaiting the promise, so it will return before the `signIn` promise is completed." By returning the promise in my `signIn` , i will effectively be awaiting this promise in my event listener?

Comment: @user2954945 I've updated my answer to provide a more complete explanation.

Comment: Awesome explanation!  Thanks a lot!  I learned a lot from this.